# (Swift) Storing and retrieving Array to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store an array to `NSUserDefaults` and retrieve the array when needed to populate a `UITableView`.

Currently I am using:

```
//store data
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey: "\(identity.text!)listA")                    
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

//retrieve data
let tabledata = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("\(identity.text!)listA")
myArray = [tabledata!]
tableView.reloadData()
```

But I get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found `nil` while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

when trying to load the data. I am not sure if the issue is in the storage or the retrieval. Has anyone been through this before?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From your code I see you are storing some array

```
// Your code
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey: "\(identity.text!)listA")
```

and retrieving a string

```
//Your code
let tabledata = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("\(identity.text!)listA")
```

There is probably a type mismatch, You store one type and retrieve another type.

While retrieving either use `arrayForKey()` or `objectForKey()` see the code below.

```
let tabledata = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("\(identity.text!)listA")
```

or

```
let tabledata = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("\(identity.text!)listA")
```

If it is an array I would go with First one.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the way that you can store and retrieved array of object with help of `NSKeyArchive`.

**To Store array to NSUserDefault.**

```
let placesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: placesArray)
UserDefaults.standard.set(placesData, forKey: "places")
```

**To Retrieved array from NSUserDefault.**

```
let placesData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "places") as? NSData

if let placesData = placesData {
    let placesArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: placesData as Data) as? [Place]
    print(placesArray)
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: For custom object array it's not working can you please help me out.
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: customeobject array)

Answer (score 10):

## Saving and Retrieving a String array to UserDefaults

Save array

```
let array = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
```

Retrieve array

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedStringArray") as? [String] ?? [String]()
```

See more at [How to save user settings using NSUserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 2):

What are you storing in the array?

If it's objects it won't work, if It's just strings or numbers then it should be fine.

Next steps you take should be to turn on exception breakpoints and maybe println() everything you can so you can pinpoint the exact whereabouts of the problem.

As a shot in the dark I would suggest maybe (identity.text!) is coming out as nil

Also you should probably change it to this

```
if let tabledata: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("\(identity.text!)listA"){

    myArray = [tabledata!]

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This will make the code not even try to run unless there is a value it can use

Comment: I printed identity.text! and that is working properly. So the issue is not there. I tried running your code but I still get the same error.

Comment: println("\(tabledata)') is what is returning nil

Answer (score 2):

**Latest swift3  version to store array of data into userdefaults and get that array of data using keys**

```
    let nameArray = ["Ramu","JAGAN","Steve","Swift"]
    let namesArrayData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: nameArray)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(namesArrayData, forKey: "arrayData")
```

RetriveData

```
        let retriveArrayData= UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:  "arrayData") as? NSData

   if let retriveArrayData= namesArrayData{
  let retriveArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: namesArraydata as Data) as? [nameArray]
  print(retriveArray )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed in swift 3. 
Note that this works with device but not playground or simulator

```
//store the array
let array = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

defaults.setValue(array, forKey: "history")

defaults.synchronize()

//Retrieve the array
if((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "history")) != nil){
    let historyWords = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "history") as? [String])!
    print(historyWords)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Store into User Default:**

```
let arrayFruit = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon"]    
 //store in user default
UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayFruit, forKey: "arrayFruit")
```

**Retrieving array from User Defaults:**

```
if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayFruit") as? [String]{
    print(arr)
}
```

Comment: Ya ill take care of it. Thanks @Moritz