# iOS: how to convert NSUserDefaults stored AnyObject type to array

Tags: ios, swift, types, casting

I have put an array into NSUserDefaults() like so:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(users, forKey: "usersArray")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Then I pull it out like so:

```
fetchedUserArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("usersArray")
```

The problem I am facing is that once it is removed from NSUserDefaults it is of type NSArray, preventing me from manipulating it like a Swift array. I have tried this to convert the type, however the compiler does not recognize the variable "castedUsersArray" when it is used later in the code despite not raising any errors upon type casting:

```
var fetchedArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("usersArray") as? NSArray
var castedUsersArray = fetchedArray as AnyObject as [String]
```

I have spent a very long time on this with no success. The type constraints of Swift are driving me nuts.
Thank you,
Nick

Comment: `as AnyObject` doesn't mean that you cast....eventually you define that the variable is of type AnyObject

Comment: if you store array then retrieve like this NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("usersArray")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Swift) Storing and retrieving Array to NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118735/swift-storing-and-retrieving-array-to-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Don't cast the `objectForKey` to an Array but rather an Array containing a certain type like you did with castedUsersArray. Don't throw away type information like you did with fetchedArray.

```
let users = ["Amy", "Bill", "Cindy"]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(users, forKey: "usersArray")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

let fetched = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("usersArray") as? [String] ?? []
```

The nil coalescing at the end of the line handles the empty NSUserDefaults case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, however I am still receiving errors when attempting to retrieve the array from NSUserDefaults() on a separate view. Here is the error I am getting: "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'. Even after adding the ';' in between the double question marks it does not work. Whenever I try to use the array later in the code I am met with a "use of unresolved identifier 'fetched'

Answer (score 0):

**NSUserDefaults** has a specific method to get your stored string arrays called [stringArrayForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/stringArrayForKey:):

```
let stringArray = ["Hello","playground"]
```

store your string array

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(stringArray, forKey: "stringArray")
```

load it when needed

```
if let loadedStringArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringArrayForKey("stringArray") {
    print(loadedStringArray)   // ["Hello", "playground"]
}
```