# Swift persistent storage

Tags: ios, swift, persistent-storage

I am trying to make an app that has to store some values, but i don't know how to do it.

```
struct mat {
    var a: String
    var b: [Int]
    var c: Double
}        

var subj = [mat]()
```

I had a look at CoreData but i didn't understand it, can it store arrays?

this  is what i would like to save and have access to after the app is reloaded.

How can i save the array of structures? or each individual structure? or can i do it some other way?

P.S. I don't have a lot of experience in coding with swift

Comment: core data can store arrays.

Comment: You can start with NSUserDefaults instead of CoreData this topic can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118735/swift-storing-and-retrieving-array-to-nsuserdefaults

Comment: look up NSUserDefaults

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If you just doing a simple app for practice/tutorial purposes, you should be fine with storing your data to UserDefaults.

```
// to store
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(yourArray, forKey:"yourArray")
userDefaults.synchronize()

// to retrieve
var yourArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("yourArray")
```